# How to point the camera towards a SCNVector3 point below iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, trigonometry

I just started learning how to use `SceneKit` yesterday, so I may get some stuff wrong or incorrect. I am trying to make my `cameraNode` look at a `SCNVector3` point in the scene.

I am trying to make my app available to people below `iOS 11.0`. However, the `look(at:)` function is only for `iOS 11.0+`.

Here is my function where I initialise the camera:

```
func initCamera() {
    cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(5, 12, 10)
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        cameraNode.look(at: SCNVector3(0, 5, 0)) // Calculate the look angle
    } else {
        // How can I calculate the orientation? <-----------
    }
    print(cameraNode.rotation) // Prints: SCNVector4(x: -0.7600127, y: 0.62465125, z: 0.17941462, w: 0.7226559)
    gameScene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
}
```

The orientation of `SCNVector4(x: -0.7600127, y: 0.62465125, z: 0.17941462, w: 0.7226559)` in degrees is `x: -43.5, y: 35.8, z: 10.3`, and I don't understand `w`. (Also, why isn't `z = 0`? I thought `z` was the roll...?)

Here is my workings out for recreating what I thought the **Y-angle** should be:

[image]

So I worked it out to be `63.4 degrees`, but the returned rotation shows that it should be `35.8 degrees`. Is there something wrong with my calculations, do I not fully understand `SCNVector4`, or is there another method to do this?

I looked at [Explaining in Detail the ScnVector4 method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29019306/explaining-in-detail-the-scnvector4-method/29030017#29030017) for what `SCNVector4` is, but I still don't really understand what `w` is for. It says that `w` is the 'angle of rotation' which I thought was what I thought X, Y & Z were for.

---

**If you have any questions, please ask!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although **@rickster** has given the explanations of the properties of the node, I have figured out a method to rotate the node to look at a point using maths (trigonometry).

Here is my code:

```
// Extension for Float
extension Float {
    /// Convert degrees to radians
    func asRadians() -> Float {
        return self * Float.pi / 180
    }
}
```

and also:

```
// Extension for SCNNode
extension SCNNode {
    /// Look at a SCNVector3 point
    func lookAt(_ point: SCNVector3) {
        // Find change in positions
        let changeX = self.position.x - point.x // Change in X position
        let changeY = self.position.y - point.y // Change in Y position
        let changeZ = self.position.z - point.z // Change in Z position

        // Calculate the X and Y angles
        let angleX = atan2(changeZ, changeY) * (changeZ > 0 ? -1 : 1)
        let angleY = atan2(changeZ, changeX)

        // Calculate the X and Y rotations
        let xRot = Float(-90).asRadians() - angleX // X rotation
        let yRot = Float(90).asRadians() - angleY // Y rotation
        self.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(CGFloat(xRot), CGFloat(yRot), 0) // Rotate
    }
}
```

And you call the function using:

```
cameraNode.lookAt(SCNVector3(0, 5, 0))
```

Hope this helps people in the future!

Comment: Yeah, that works. Note too that `SCNAction.rotateTo` is equivalent to setting `eulerAngles` directly if the animation duration is zero.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to express a 3D rotation in SceneKit:

1. What you're doing on paper is calculating separate angles around the x, y, and z axes. These are called [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles), or pitch, yaw, and roll. You might get results that more resemble your hand-calculations if you use `eulerAngles` or [`simdEulerAngles`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/2881859-simdeulerangles) instead of `rotation. (Or you might not, because one of the difficulties of an Euler-angle system is that you have to apply each of those three rotations in the correct order.)
2. [`simdRotation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/2881845-simdrotation) or `rotation` uses a four-component vector (`float4` or `SCNVector4`) to express an [axis-angle representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation) of the rotation. This relies on a bit of math that isn't obvious for many newcomers to 3D graphics: the result of any sequence of rotations around different axes can be minimally expressed as a single rotation around a new axis.

   > For example, a rotation of π/2 radians (90°) around the z-axis (0,0,1) followed by a rotation of π/2 around the y-axis (0,1,0) has the same result as a rotation of 2π/3 around the axis (-1/√3, 1/√3, 1/√3).

   **This is where you're getting confused about the x, y, z, and w components of a SceneKit `rotation` vector** — the first three components are lengths, expressing a 3D vector, and the fourth is a rotation in radians around that vector.
3. [Quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) are another way to express 3D rotation (and one that's even further off the beaten path for those of us with the formal math education common to undergraduate computer science curricula, but not crazy advanced, either). These have lots of great features for 3D graphics, like being easy to compose and interpolate between. In SceneKit, the [`simdOrientation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/2881854-simdorientation) or `orientation` property lets you work with a node's rotation as a quaternion.

   Explaining how quaternions work is too much for one SO answer, but the practical upshot is this: if you're working with a good vector math library (like the [SIMD library built into iOS 9 and later](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/simd/working_with_quaternions)), you can basically treat them as opaque — just convert from whichever other rotation representation is easiest for you, and reap the benefits.